Cloudfront signed url gets invalidated if accessing from different clients
I have generated a cloudfront url, and I can access the file fine before the url expires, as long as I use the same client for accessing it. The second I use that url on a different client (e.g. browser first, then curl) the url gets invalidated. Why is that?

I don't know why but changing the ACL from object writer is object owner to bucket owner preferred has fixed the issue.
